# Adding additional MAPI email account via PowerShell on existing email profile

Tags: windows, powershell, outlook, registry

I'm looking for a way to take an existing email profile i.e. default "Outlook" and programmatically (preferably via Powershell) add another email account to the profile, so the end-user gets an additional email account. It should run one-time and if the 2nd profile with specific string exists - would skip and complete.

I don't know if it's possible, to the email should be comprised of firstname.lastname@domain.com - is it possible to use User Display name for the firstname.lastname part of the email?

Comment: You _could_ try and split the `DisplayName` into first- and lastname, but there are specific properties a user object has for that: `GivenName` is the Firstname, `Surname` is the users lastname. I would use those. cmdlet `Get-ADUser` will return these properties by default too.

Comment: What kind of email account are you adding to a profile?

Comment: Google Workspace account